# Recommendations for an experienced programmer new to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

I come from a C/Unix background, with a lot of experience in shell scripting, and some on Perl, elisp, etc. too. But now I'm getting into some work where I'll need to be developing interactive web-based interfaces, and I need to learn JavaScript. My problem is that all the resources I've found online for learning JavaScript seem to be targeted at an audience who's never programmed, and their authors don't seem much better. As soon as I see "validating user input to take the load off your server" as one of the great uses for JS, I want to scream and I feel like I can't trust anything else the author says. ;-)

Can anyone recommend good resources for an experienced programmer wanting to learn JS as a new language? Ideally I'd like to get started online, but dead tree recommendations would be welcome too, especially if I can preview them online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best javascript book (for an experienced coder)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655530/best-javascript-book-for-an-experienced-coder)

Comment: To me, The odin project's been the best. Its's open sourced and very detailed because it uses in-house explanations + outsourced explanations by linking to other pages for providing opinions, contexts, etc. https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/foundations/courses/foundations

Answer (score 10):

A great JavaScript book for experienced programmers is Doug Crockford's [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748). It's short, assumes you know what you're doing, is opinionated, and is not a tutorial.

Comment: Balance that out with the fact that Crockford comes across as (and IS, arguably) a zealot. He'll instruct you "not" to use parts of the language. Takes some with a grain of salt, as with all Zealots :) But really, +1 for a good book.

Comment: Yeah, I just previewed it on Google. As an example of what you're saying, I'd heard about type conversions using `-0`, `|0`, etc., which I *love* coming from using things like `0U+` to convert to `unsigned` in C, but I get the feeling he strongly disapproves of this sort of usage.. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

My advice: Forget what you know about object oriented programming.  Attempts to apply the inheritance paradigms from an OO language have repeatedly overcomplicated many, many chunks of JS code.

Prototyping is not Class construction.  Object instantiation is not Class instantiation.  "Classes" are not real.

There are ways to get what you want.  You can even have something akin to privates - but they are not methods or members.  They are merely locally scoped.  Inheritance is often faked, but with mixed results, and universally at the expense of data hiding.

Javascript is prototyped.  It is not object oriented.  Keep that in mind every time you think something like, "Man, an interface here would be awesome..."

Comment: Thankfully I come from a C background, not an OO background, so I don't have too much to forget. :-)

Comment: Oh.  Then may I suggest, jQuery: Novice to Ninja

Answer (score 4):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655530/best-javascript-book-for-an-experienced-coder/3655693#3655693

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594159/best-book-to-learn-web-development-for-a-professional-developer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books

but I will recommend these two fantastic books, which teach me a lot.

[image][image]

Comment: Sadly all those three linked questions seem to have been removed.  Stack Overflow never ceases to disappoint by closing valuable questions, now deleting content?!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net). It doesn't cover everything, but it will move you towards idiomatic JavaScript programming -- things like functional programming, closures and prototypes. (The online version comes complete with a sandbox tutorial environment.) The rest, after all, is just knowing how to use references.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript Guide from Mozilla Developer Network, a simple and yet informative guide, gives beginners a big picture of JS in a short time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 2):

*JavaScript: the definitive guide* is one of my favorite programming books:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992